# Loop through an if statement?

Tags: php, loops, if-statement

I'm creating user levels based on how many days a user is registered. 
That way I want to create messages such as "happy first anniversary on this website" etc.

So far I built it with code like below.

```
// count days
$interval_obj->days;  // final variable counting the days a user has registered. e.g. 50 days

// array of number of levels. e.g. 25
$levels = apply_filters( 'hook_member_levels', array(       
    '1' => esc_html__('1 Level', $this->textdomain), 
    '2' => esc_html__('2 Levels', $this->textdomain),
    //...etc
) );

$one_min    = $option['level-1-min']; // e.g. 1 day
$one_max    = $option['level-1-max']; // e.g. 30 days
$two_min    = $option['level-2-min']; // e.g. 31 days
$two_max    = $option['level-2-max']; // e.g. 90 days
...etc.

if( $interval_obj->days >= $one_min && $interval_obj->days <= $one_max ) {             
    $output = 'level-1';
} elseif( $interval_obj->days >= $two_min && $interval_obj->days <= $two_max ) { 
    $output = 'level-2';
} elseif(){
    //... etc.
}
```

Outcome; the current user will fall in level 2 (50 days).

Although this works, I'm looking for a more efficient/cleaner way to code this (like inside a loop)
Something like this:

```
$how_many_levels = count( $levels );    

for( $i = 0; $i <= $how_many_levels; $i++ ) {

    ${ $i .'_min' } = $option['level-'.$i.'-min'];
    ${ $i .'_max'} = $option['level-'.$i.'-max'];

    if( $interval_obj->days >= ${ $i .'_min' } && $interval_obj->days <= ${ $i .'_max' } ) { 
        $output = 'level-'.$i;
    } else {
        $output = '0';
    }

}

return $output;
```

Needless to say, this doesn't work. `$i` is `25` (number of levels), not 1,2,3,4...25. So this code reads as

```
if( $interval_obj->days >= 9125 && $interval_obj->days <= 9490 ) { 
    $output = 'level-25';
} else {
    $output = '0';
}
```

Outcome is `0` because the user is only registered for 50 days.

Is there are better approach (that works)?

Comment: More people may see your post if you tag it with the language this code's written in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your main problem is that your loop runs from `0` to `number of levels`, but there is no level `0`.

I tested this code fragment:

```
<?php

$option['level-1-min'] = 1; 
$option['level-1-max'] = 30; 
$option['level-2-min']= 31; 
$option['level-2-max'] = 90; 
$option['level-3-min']= 91; 
$option['level-3-max'] = 120; 
$option['level-4-min']= 121; 
$option['level-4-max'] = 150; 

$days = 50;

for( $i = 1; $i <= 4; $i++ ) {

    ${ $i .'_min' } = $option['level-'.$i.'-min'];
    ${ $i .'_max'} = $option['level-'.$i.'-max'];

    if( $days >= ${ $i .'_min' } && $days <= ${ $i .'_max' } ) { 
        $output = 'level-'.$i;
    } else {
        $output = '0';
    }
    echo $output."\n";
}
```

and it produced this output:

```
0
level-2
0
0
```

Which I think is what you wanted.

Obviously I hard-coded the levels array and a few variables, but you should provide the start you need.

Comment: Works! I already see where it went wrong. `$output` was placed outside the loop. I ended up changing `$output` to an array, removed all `0` values and then return it as a string.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest creating an algorithm rather than having a loop with hard coded levels. For example, assuming the user level increment at a fix rate of 30 days the simple algorithm below will accurately and indefinitely generate a user level.

```
function calculateLevel($days){        
    $level = ceil(($days + .1) / 30) ?: 1;

    return "level-{$level}";
}
```

At day 30 the level will be 2, at 60 level 3 and so on...

```
0 --> level-1
1 --> level-1
29 --> level-1
30 --> level-2
31 --> level-2
59 --> level-2
60 --> level-3
61 --> level-3
89 --> level-3
90 --> level-4
91 --> level-4
```

If the rate the levels increment is not fixed you can still use this approach to increase the gap between levels. Ex: after 90 days increase levels every 45 days, after 120 days increase levels every 60 days and so on.